# is there any way to change a out ref Boolean that was send as a param in java?

Tags: java, android, boolean

I know there is a Boolean object in java.

I want to send a Boolean param and change its value inside method.

Obviously this cannot be done as Objects are passed by coping the obj reference

so assigning a new value would not take effect outside of the method.

here is my code

```
final Boolean finalIsShownFlag = isShownFlag;

Runnable closeRunnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {        
    closeTooltip(finalIsShownFlag, finalCurrentTooltip);
  }
};
```

whereas `isShownFlag` is a reference to a Boolean member (every time it's another Boolean member).

```
  private void closeTooltip(Boolean isShown, LinearLayout tooltipLayout) {
    if (isShown) {
      isShown = false;
      tooltipLayout.clearAnimation();
      tooltipLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use an `AtomicBoolean` for this, or an `AtomicReference<Boolean>`. Or just make your method return a `boolean`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare it as `instance variable`, so you will change the same reference each time.

```
public class MyClass {

    private Boolean isShownFlag = false;
    private void closeTooltip(LinearLayout tooltipLayout) {
        if(isShownFlag) {//code}
    }
}
```

Or you could use `AtomicBoolean` as `fge` suggest, here you will be able to change the same reference.

```
private void closeTooltip(AtomicBoolean isShown, LinearLayout tooltipLayout) {
    if(isShownFlag) {//code}
}
```